# Why is my request to Printful's API denied access?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

So, I'm trying to make a call to the Printful API. First of all, I followed the "How to start" section from the [documentation page](https://www.printful.com/docs). Under the "Stores" option I set the URL to point to my website after which I went into the "API" option and generated my API key.
The way I made the request is based on the "Authorization" section, also from the docs. As far as I understand, the only thing I need to do is send the Authorization header with the API key encoded using base64, and that it should work.

```
var API_KEY = '---';
var API_KEY64 = btoa(API_KEY);

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.printful.com/products',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + API_KEY64
  },
  dataType: 'JSON',
  type: 'GET',

  complete: function (data) {
    if (data.readyState == '4' && data.status == '200') {
      p.innerHTML = 'success';
    }
    else {
      p.innerHTML = 'error';
    }
  }
});
```

What happens when I run this code is that the **p** element's inner HTML becomes error, and I get this error in my console:

[image: Error]

I've tried excluding the headers to see what would happen: I get a similiar error, except there is no part about the pre-flight check:

[image: Error(No Headers)]

If I send the request straight to 'https://api.printful.com'(doesn't make sense to send requests here; it was just to see what I get back), what I get is:

[image: No endpoint]

I've also sent multiple emails to Printful's dev support over a period of four days, but I haven't heard anything from them yet.

Information about the API on the internet is very scarce. I literally found only one person asking a question about it. There are no tutorials or examples of code anywhere.

I've also researched a little about Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, hoping that Access-Control-Allow-Origin is something I can set on the client-side(again, wouldn't make sense; just a shot in the dark).

Thanks for any help and/or insights in advance.

Comment: *"I've also researched a little about Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, hoping that Access-Control-Allow-Origin is something I can set on the client-side"* - That would defeat the whole purpose.

Comment: [You MUST use a `server-language`.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/why-is-the-same-origin-policy-so-important)

Comment: Sounds like you have to ask them why they do not have CORS enabled. My guess, they don't want you to do it from the browser.

Comment: I sincerely hope that that's not your actual API key. If so, make sure it is blocked and changed ASAP. Those keys are like passwords and you must keep them private. It even says so on the tutorial page you said you followed: *"Keep the API key in secret, and never expose it in any public website's client-side code."* So that's probably also the reason this doesn't work: the code is not intended to run in a browser at all. The page should make a call to your server, which can then make a call to their service on behalf of your visitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Printful have not configured their API server to allow cross-origin Ajax requests.

Note that they provide a number of [client libraries](https://www.printful.com/docs/libraries) for several different languages, but not for client-side JavaScript.

Note also that in the page they link to, they have this to say about your API key:

> Keep the API key in secret, and never expose it in any public website's client-side code.

(Note that you have now posted your API key in a Stackoverflow question, where it is public, will have been indexed by search engines, and cached. You need to get Printful to destroy it and create a new one now.)